# I sent BTC from Blockchain to a BTH wallet on Coinbase.. can I get it back?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

So not knowing Coinbase had just recently added BTH to their wallets I accidentally copied and pasted that address to transfer my bitcoin to. It's been confirmed on Blockchain & the coin is unspent. Is there anyway I can retrieve this coin?

Comment: do you mean BCH(Bitcoin-Cash) instead of BTH?

Comment: Yes  that is what I meant